# Explicitly calling templated overload of operator<< gives error

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, template-specialization

I have the following code:

```
//.hpp
enum class UIDCategory
{
    GoodType //and others
};
typedef unsigned short UID;
typedef UID GoodType;

template<UIDCategory UIDCat> //Yes, UIDCat is supposed to go unused
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, const UID& uid)
{
    return str << uid;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, const Recipe::GoodRatio& goodRatio);

//definition of Rules here

template<>
inline std::ostream& operator<< <UIDCategory::GoodType>(std::ostream& str, const GoodType& goodType)
{
    return str << Rules::goods.at(goodType);
}

//.cpp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, const Recipe::GoodRatio& goodRatio)
{
    return str.template operator<< <UIDCategory::GoodType>(goodRatio.goodType);
}
```

I am using VC++17.
I get the following error on the line in the function in the .cpp file:

```
Rules.cpp(21): error C2677: binary '<': no global operator found which takes type 'UIDCategory' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

I have been searching the web for a solution and I found out that the `template` keyword is necessary in the call to `operator<< <UIDCategory::GoodType>(goodRatio.goodType)` to denote that `operator<<` is actually a template so I added it as shown but the error doesn't go away. What am I doing wrong here?

The whole idea here is to provide a work-around for the limitation that typedefs do not introduce a new type and therefore cannot be used in overload resolution. I ran into trouble when I simply introduced the following overload: `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, const GoodType& goodType)`. This header is equivalent to `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, const unsigned short& goodType)` and so `str << aGoodType`is ambiguous (it clashes with the one in `std`).

My code is an attempt to enable the user to explicitly state what 'overload' of the << operator is to be used by making a templated overload of the << operator and then explicitly specializing it for the different members of `UIDCategory`.

I'd appreciate any help on both the error and on the thing that I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: You should provide a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While making my Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example as suggested by Jonas I actually solved the problem. The problem was that I was using the wrong calling convention of the << operator.
I called it as if it is a member of the stream while it isn't.
So it should be `operator<<<UIDCategory::GoodType>(str, goodRatio.goodType)` instead of `str.template operator<< <UIDCategory::GoodType>(goodRatio.goodType)`.

Also I decided that this is way to convoluted anyway for what I was trying to achieve and chose a simpler method with some minor drawbacks.